# Загрузить картинку не получается

Tags: java, android, firebase, picasso, firebase-android

Ребята, мне нужно сделать следующее:
Если у пользователя нету своей аватарки,то нужно поставить ему дефолтную картинку.
Но у меня это не получается. Работаю с Picasso.

```
    final CircularImageView photo=(CircularImageView)mParent.findViewById(R.id.main_photo);

    myRefImage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid()+"/img.jpg");
    if(myRefImage.getDownloadUrl()==null){
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.logo).into(photo);
    }else{
        myRefImage.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(uri).into(photo);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Что именно не получается - не понятно. Условие не срабатывает? Картинка не загружается? Проверить ссылку на `null` не вышло? В чём именно у вас проблема? Напишите это в вопросе. Пока что вам никак не помочь.А ещё `Picasso` немного устарел и модно юзать `Glide`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в том-то и проблема,что я не понимаю,что не работает. Вроде бы написано,как по мне, правильно,но по итогу изображение дефолтное не ставится,если нету аватарки пользователя.

Comment: Выясните для начала что у вас вообще исполнение в ваш `if` заходит. Если так - то весь остальной код из вопроса лишний. И `firebase` тут не при чём. Сократите вопрос убрав всё лишнее

Answer (score 1):

Picasso поддерживает плейсхолдеры и во время загрузки и при ошибке.

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);
```

Запрос повторяется три раза перед тем как будет показан плейсхолдер ошибки.
[Picasso PLACE HOLDERS](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Таким образом используйте следующий код:

```
final CircularImageView photo = (CircularImageView) mParent.findViewById(R.id.main_photo);
String imageUrl =  FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid()+"/img.jpg").getDownloadUrl();
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
    .load(imageUrl)
    .error(R.drawable.logo)
    .into(photo);
```